# The First Dropdown Is Always Being Open

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I am trying to have **multiple dropdowns** on my website. The problem is whenever I clicked the **second dropdown** the **first dropdown** was being opened. I got the codes from *w3school* and I honestly don't get it but it works so it was fine with me until this happens,

Below are my codes.

```html
<html>
<title> Dropdown </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<body>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
    <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown I 
                </button>
    <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
    </div><br>

    <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-2')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown II 
                </button>
    <div id="demoAcc-2" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
    </div><br>

    <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-3')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown III 
                </button>
    <div id="demoAcc-3" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
      <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myAccFunc(elemId) {
      var x = document.getElementById(elemId);
      if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
      } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: HTML id attributes must contain unique values.

Comment: `document.getElementById("elemId");` You want to use the function parameter `document.getElementById(elemId);` instead of a string literal.

Comment: Why do you try it this way? There are `<select><option>` dropdowns builtin in the browsers and your scripted look'n'feel can be implemented using pure CSS.

Comment: That really helps! Thank you!! @Quasimodo'sclone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**
Your function are opening the same property ID `demoAcc` for all

**SOLUTION**: you will need to specify unique ID's for each different element, like:

```
<div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">...</div>
<div id="demoAcc-2" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">...</div>
<div id="demoAcc-3" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">...</div>
```

Then you need to update your function to receive a value:

```
function myAccFunc( elemId ) {
            var x = document.getElementById( elemId );
...
}
```

Then on each button you will define the div ID you wish to open, like:

```
<button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc')" ... > Dropdown I </button>
<button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-2')" ... > Dropdown II </button>
<button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-3')" ... > Dropdown III </button>
```

See snippet:

```js
function myAccFunc( elemId ) {
            var x = document.getElementById( elemId );
            if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
              x.className += " w3-show";
            } else {
              x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
            }
          }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
          
            <div class="sidenav">
           <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown I 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
            </div><br>
            
            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-2')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn-2"> Dropdown II 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc-2" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
            </div><br>
            
            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-3')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn-3"> Dropdown III 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc-3" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: I edited my codes and applied your answer but I got an error. Please refer to my post above so you can see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your snippet to pass the ID of the element to the function.

```html
<html>
      <title> Dropdown </title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
     <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
      
      <body>
        <div class="sidenav">
       <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
        <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc1')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown I 
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc1" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
        </div><br>
        
        <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc2')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown II 
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc2" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
        </div><br>
        
        <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc3')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown III 
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc3" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
          <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
        </div>
     </div>
      
      <script>
      function myAccFunc(id) {
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
          x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
          x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
      }
      </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pure CSS

This can be done with pure CSS.

In this example there are `<button>` elements just to have the browser's default style of a button. To let the checkboxes receive the mouse-clicks we turn off them on the buttons with `pointer-events:none`. You could style the `<label>` tags to look like buttons as well, so you do not need buttons at all.

The trick is to define the `display` CSS property of the next sibling of the checkboxes dependend on the checked-state.

```css
.sidenav>label>button {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidenav>input[type="checkbox"],
.sidenav>input[type="checkbox"]+div {
  display: none;
}

.sidenav>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<div class="sidenav">
  <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
  <label for="myBtn-1"><button> Dropdown I </button></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myBtn-1">
  <div id="demoAcc-1" class="w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
  </div><br>

  <label for="myBtn-2"><button> Dropdown II </button></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myBtn-2">
  <div id="demoAcc-2" class="w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
  </div><br>

  <label for="myBtn-3"><button> Dropdown III </button></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myBtn-3">
  <div id="demoAcc-3" class="w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript Method

If you really want to do it in JavaScript, you should use the modern way adding event-listeners instead of the `onclick` attribute.

Instead of string manipulation use the `classList.toggle()` method.

You do not need `id` attributes at all:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
  document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav > button').forEach(el =>
    el.addEventListener('click', ev =>
      ev.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('w3-hide')
)));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<div class="sidenav">
  <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
  <button> Dropdown I </button>
  <div class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
  </div><br>

  <button> Dropdown II </button>
  <div class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
  </div><br>

  <button> Dropdown III </button>
  <div class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
    <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function myAccFunc( elemId ) {
            var x = document.getElementById( elemId );
            if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
              x.className += " w3-show";
            } else {
              x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
            }
          }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

            <div class="sidenav">
              <h3> DROPDOWNS </h3> <br>
            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn"> Dropdown I 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">A</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">B</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">C</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">D</button>
            </div><br>

            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-2')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn-2"> Dropdown II 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc-2" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">1</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">4</button>
            </div><br>

            <button onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc-3')" href="javascript:void(0)" id="myBtn-3"> Dropdown III 
            </button>
            <div id="demoAcc-3" class="w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium">
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">+</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">-</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">/</button>
              <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button">=</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```